# How to call same function in multiple div in React?

Tags: reactjs

`<button className="readlink" onClick={this.moreToggle}>Read {this.state.expanded ? 'Less' : 'More'}...</button>`

```
moreToggle = () => {
        if(this.state.isExpanded == 'ansText'){
            this.setState({isExpanded: 'ansText ansTextExpanded'});
            this.setState({expanded: true});
        }
        else{
            this.setState({isExpanded: 'ansText'});
            this.setState({expanded: false});
        }
    }
```

I have this function moreToggle which needs to be called only for the specific div where user clicks. There are more than 1 div like this but using the above approach all div are toggled. How can this be achieved.

```
<div className="quesData ansData">
                        <div className="quesText">Does weighted blanket helps to reduce stress?</div>
                        <div className="askedDate">Asked on January 14, 2020</div>
                        <div className={this.state.isExpanded}>
                            Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets
                            Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets
                            Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets
                            Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets
                            Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets
                            Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets
                            Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets
                            Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets
                            Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets Weighted blankets
                        </div>
                        <button className="readlink" onClick={this.moreToggle}>Read {this.state.expanded ? 'Less' : 'More'}...</button>
                    </div>
```

The button is used to expand the div by adding class to the content div i.e. weighted blankets div.

Comment: Hi, Can you please share some code

Comment: Please share code

Comment: Edited to show the code of the button there are multiple buttons like this

Comment: Please share `div` code that uses `this.state.isExpanded`.(how to use it?)

Comment: Do you get an array from api and render your button and div template by received data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array of object(from api), then you can add another property to each item for expanding:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  // for example array of object received from api
  const [state,setState]=useState([{id:1,title:"first"},{id:2,title:"second"}]);

  const moreToggle=(id)=>{
    let result=state.find(item=>item.id===id);
    // add isExpanded property to each item of array or change it
    // now each item of array is like this: {id:1,title:"first", isExpanded:true or false}
    result.isExpanded=!result.isExpanded;
    setState([...state]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {state.map(item=>
      <div>
        <div className={item.isExpanded ? "show":"hidden"}>your {item.title} div</div>
        <button onClick={()=> moreToggle(item.id)}>Read {item.isExpanded ? 'Less' : 'More'}...</button>
      </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is working but what is `setState([...state]);` you may find this dumb but I am learning react so not aware of that. How can I use multiple states here with different data stored e.g `this.state = {
          isExpanded: false,
          setPhoto: 'myPhoto',
        };`

Comment: My code is base on react-hooks.In react hooks you can declare multiple state.Please look at this link "https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html"

Answer (score 1):

You can assign each `<div>` an id like `"div-1"`, in this case I use an enum: `collapsibleFields.FIELD_1` and passed to the `moreToggle` function and change our state to key-value pairs.

```
state = {
 expanded: {},
 isExpanded: {},
};

const collapsibleFields = {
   FIELD_1 = 'FIELD_1',
   FIELD_2 = 'FIELD_2',
   // etc
}
```

```
<button className="readlink" onClick={() => this.moreToggle(collapsibleFields.FIELD_1)}>Read {this.state.expanded[collapsibleFields.FIELD_1] ? 'Less' : 'More'}...</button>
```

```
 <div className="quesText">Does weighted blanket helps to reduce stress?</div>
                        <div className="askedDate">Asked on January 14, 2020</div>
                        <div className={this.state.isExpanded[collapsibleFields.FIELD_1]}>
```

```
moreToggle = (id) => {
        this.setState({
             expanded[id]: this.state.isExpanded[id] === 'ansText'
      });
    }
```

Comment: I am newbie here can you please elaborate how can I use enum here. I am trying above solution but will be better to improve also so that's why asking for help.

Comment: @ghostbbbmt-MSP `enum` in js is like an object, then must use `:` instead of `=`

Comment: @ghostbbbmt-MSP What to do if these divs are dynamically rendered on API calls then the enum will not be that useful right?

Comment: @Kurona, you can use their `index` as `id`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have added `name` attribute to each clickable and in click handle I have passed the `sytheticEvent` which will give us the clicked elements name back.

```js
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState({});
  const moreToggle = useCallback((e) => {
    const name = e.currentTarget.name;
    console.log(name);

    setMyState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: !prevState[name],
    }))
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <button className="readlink" name="btn1" onClick={moreToggle}>
        Read {myState.btn1 ? "Less" : "More"}...
      </button>

      <button className="readlink" name="btn2" onClick={moreToggle}>
        Read {myState.btn2 ? "Less" : "More"}...
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Okay I will try this but again what if all the divs or buttons here are dynamically generated using API call then will name be useful?

Comment: Yes, as you will generate the `div` assign the `name` attribute to div at the same time. But be careful, name should be unique otherwise you will face the same issue, which you are facing now.

Comment: In the mean time you can have a look working example from [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-thunder-h8xo2)

Comment: Please take a look at the div in my code and help me to understand how this can be achieved

Comment: Please have a look [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-thunder-h8xo2), It will show how it will work.

Comment: Hey, Had you got a chance to check?